# with passport.js make strategy what use req.params instead req.body

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I make this strategy where I try auth by url parameters. It call from java code.

url looks like: http://localhost/mc/download/filename/user@server.com/secretpass

this strategy:

```
passport.use('mc-login', new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form

    // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
    // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
    User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  req.params.uname }, function(err, user) {
        // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
        if (err)
            return done(err);

        // if no user is found, return the message
        if (!user)
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash

        // if the user is found but the password is wrong
        if (!user.validPassword(req.params.upass))
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

        // all is well, return successful user
        return done(null, user);
    });

}));
```

I try call it in this code:

```
app.get('/mc/download/:fname/:uname/:upass',

        function(req, res, next) {
      passport.authenticate('mc-login', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
          if (err) { return next(err); }
          return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
        });
      })(req, res, next);
    }

    ,function(req, res){
    ...
```

but in info variable it return the
`[stack=undefined,name="BadRequestError",message="Missing credentials"]`
and user is empty

How make strategy what allow to auth with `req.params` variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocalStrategy` requires a username and password to be present in either `req.query` or `req.body`. If any of those aren't present, the strategy verification handler won't get called (which is why even with `passReqToCallback` it doesn't work).

You can trick Passport into thinking they were set by adding an extra middleware that populates the username and password from the URL parameters:

```
app.get(
  '/mc/download/:fname/:uname/:upass',
  function(req, res, next) {
    // Populate username and password before passing it on to Passport.
    req.query.username = req.params.uname;
    req.query.password = req.params.upass;
    next();
  },
  function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('mc-login', function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
      });
    })(req, res, next);
  }
);
```